# fastest c arithmetic method for ints

Tags: c, math, binary, overflow

I am writing a c program. I have an unsigned integer (16bit) whose value could be anything at any time and I have a signed char (8bit) whose value could be anything at any time, within the obvious limits of the data types. I need to add the signed char to the unsigned int, the result being an unsigned int, and if the value overflows either past 0xFFFF or below 0x00, i need the result to equal the limit (either 0x00 or 0xFFFF). I want to know what would be the fastest approach to doing this? My approach is shown below but it uses a long data type and thus long binary arithmetic so I am guessing that there is a faster way...

```
long i;
unsigned int result;

i = someUINT + someCHAR;

if(i <= 0) 
{
    result = 0;
}
else if(i >= 0xFFFF)
{
    result = 0xFFFF;
}
else 
{
    result = (unsigned int)i;
}
```

EDIT: I am using a 16bit MCU (PIC24HJ series) and the Microchip C30 compiler.

Comment: What hardware is this supposed to be run on?  The answer to this question solely depends on the hardware platform.

Comment: If using a `long` (which I assume would be twice the word size on this alleged processor?) is too slow, then you may want to drop down to assembly level so you can check the overflow flag.

Comment: @Mike Caron: I am not necessarily saying that using the long it TOO slow, I am just wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: @Mike Caron: Could you post an answer with a basic example of what that would look like. I won't be upset if it's not exactly right for my processor.

Comment: @Jordan: I'd love to post an answer, but I don't do machine assembly. (.NET assembly, sure... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly, the correct answer is

```
if(i <= 0) 
{
    result = 0;
}
else if(i >= 0xFFFF)
{
    result = 0xFFFF;
}
else 
{
    result = (unsigned int)i;
}
```

Profile the application, and if this turns out to be a bottle-neck (which I highly, highly doubt), then rewrite it.

---

Modern compilers are very good at writing branchless-conditionals for code like this, so just write it the way that makes the most sense and let the compiler do its job.  Don't confuse both the compiler and whatever poor person has to read this code in the future by using some convoluted bit-fiddling hack.

Comment: @Jordan: Also, though I don't know your specific use-case, you probably mean to use [`UINT_MAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h) rather than `0xFFFF`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the long checking before adding:

```
if(0xFFFF - someUINT < someCHAR) {
  return 0xFFFF;
} else {
  return someUINT + someCHAR;
}
```

Of course, if you REALLY need this to be FAST, turn this into an inline function or macro and go assembly.

Comment: Don't forget someCHAR can be negative: `someUINT = 10; someCHAR = -42;` .... hmmm ... and you need to be extra careful for the "integral promotions" and "usual arithmetic conversions"!!!

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm only works in 2's complement.

When checking a signed addition for overflow, the result must have the same sign as at least one of the operands. This case turns out to be only slightly different; if the result flips the "sign" bit then it's OK if both operands have the same "sign" bit. And of course the computation of the unsigned limits is easier!

```
uint16_t UIntPlusChar(uint16_t u, char ch)
{
  int16_t i = (int16_t)u;
  int16_t p = i + ch;
  if ((ch ^ i) < 0 && (p ^ i) < 0)
    p = i >> 15;
  return (uint16_t)p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow I love stuff like this. Here is my stab assuming that most of the time it will fall in between the boundaries try this

```
    long i;
    i= char + int;
    if((i & 0xFFFF) == i){
      return (int)i;
    }
    else if(i < 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      return 0xFFFF;
    }
```

Comment: Why would *adding* an operation make it faster?

Comment: @BlueRaja,  `if ((i & 0xFFFF) == i)` is 2 super fast (register only) instructions w/ branch, that's supposed to be predicted as well. If that's the case, that's staying the boundaries, the solution is good! (not just good but best of all, offered); Edit, now I see the CPU is 16bit only, not so hot

Comment: @bestsss: ...Yes, and `i >= 0xFFFF` is one instruction with branch.  Not only that, but its intent is much more clear.

Comment: @BlueRaja, `(i & 0xFFFF) == i` ensures the value of i is in the range 0-0xffff, that's the trick; it's the most common case and if predicted properly (shall be) it costs nothing. On the contrary you need 2 compare branches to ensure the same range. That speculation is probably not valid to the 16bit CPU the OP talks, I have no clue how it functions and it doesn't have a 32bit register to hold the overflown value of `i`

Comment: Considering this is for an embedded system by the sounds of it. I have worked with those compilers and they are not as advanced as people make them out to be. Anyhow I don't claim to know everything there is to know about this CPU and its branch predication, it was just my attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way will almost always be to take advantage of processor-specific features that you cannot describe in portable C code.  Write manifestly correct portable code that works, and let the compiler do what it will do.  If you have specific benchmark data that shows that this specifically must be faster, implement an additional tuned version that is processor-specific.

Many processors (including, I believe, the PIC24) have "saturating add" instructions that perform exactly this operation.  The fastest thing is typically to write assembly that uses that instruction specifically, but there's no reason to do so unless you have evidence that the function needs to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = someUINT + someCHAR;
if (someCHAR > 0)
{
   if (result < someCHAR)
   {
      result = 0xFFFF;
   }
}
else if (result > someUINT)
{
   result = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the fastest would be something like:

```
  UInt16 uival;
  Int8 sbval;
  UInt16 result;

  result = uival + sbval;
  if (uival & 0x8000)  /* Only worry about max-val overflow */
  {
    if (result = 65280) /* Underflow */
      result = 0;
  }
```

Things are a little simplified because any overflows can only happen into a small portion of the numeric range.  If the addend were 16 bits, it would be necessary to test the difference between the original uint16 and the result to see if there was overflow; since the addend is only 8 bits, that's not needed.  I've not used the PIC24xx parts, so I don't know if testing for 256 or 65280 is faster than other values, but on 8-bit parts it certainly should be.